# Stack Overflow data dump for only a few tags

Tags: discussion, data-dump

I want to have an offline copy of Stack Overflow questions and answers. I would prefer if I can download only questions with specific tags (for example, all questions tagged [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery)).

Please let me know how I can download the Stack Overflow data dump for specific tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could look into the [Stack Printer](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite).

If that doesn't meet your needs you have to write your own queries on [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/338380) something like this:

```sql
select distinct title, body
from posts p
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = p.id
inner join tags t on pt.tagid = t.id
where t.tagname in ('php', 'javascript','jquery')
```

If you export the result to CSV you can then use it off-line.